# Integral $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can you please help me with this integral

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe $x=\cos(t)$ helps.

Comment: __Hint:__ $4.0$

Comment: To make use of draks' hint, you'll need to use the [integral representation of the modified Bessel functions of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1).

Comment: $\pi I_0(1) \approx 3.977 \ne 4.0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$
Substitution:$x=\sin\theta$

$$I=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}e^{\sin\theta}d\theta$$

$$e^{\sin\theta}=1+\frac{\sin\theta}{1!}+\frac{\sin^2\theta}{2!}+\frac{\sin^3\theta}{3!}.......$$
The odd powers of sine when used in the integral will produce zero.
Again for even values of n we have
  $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^n\theta d\theta=2 \times \frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-3}{n-2}\frac{n-5}{n-4}....\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Therefore,

$$I=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}e^{\sin\theta}d\theta=\pi+2\times\Sigma\frac{1}{n!}[\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-3}{n-2}\frac{n-5}{n-4}....\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{2}]$$

$$=\pi+\pi\Sigma [\frac{1}{n(n-2)(n-4)......2}]^2$$
["n" running from two through even values ]

Writing n=2m we have,

$$\pi<I=\pi\Sigma[\frac{1}{2^m}\frac{1}{m!}]^2<4$$

[m running from  0 to infinity]

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to sort out the previous takes. For this, we will have to take as a prerequisite the series for the zeroth-order [modified Bessel function of the first kind](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25.E2)

$$I_0(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(k!)^2}\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^k$$

which can be derived from the [modified Bessel differential equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25.E1)

$$x^2 y^{\prime\prime}+xy^\prime=x^2 y$$

with initial conditions $y(0)=1,y^\prime(0)=0$.

Now,

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\exp\,x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm dx&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k!}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^k}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(2k)!}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{(x^2)^k}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm dx\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(2k)!}\int_0^1 \frac{(x^2)^k}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm dx\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(2k)!}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^{2k} u \; \cos\,u}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 u}}\mathrm du\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(2k)!}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2k} u\mathrm du\\
&=\pi\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(2k)!}\frac{(2k)!}{4^k (k!)^2}\\
&=\pi\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{(k!)^2}\left(\frac14\right)^k=\pi I_0(1)\\
\end{align*}$$

where we used the odd/even properties of the moments in the second and third lines, and the [Wallis formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) in the fifth line.