# Evaluation of Integral $\int\limits_0^1\sqrt{(1-x^2)^n} \sin(kx) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am interested in the evaluation of

$$\int^1_0 \left(1-x^2\right)^{n/2} \sin(kx)\, dx$$

Really $n$ is an odd integer here (the even case is easy).

Ooops, I think the posting

[Integral $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129743/integral-int-11-fracex-sqrt1-x2dx?rq=1)

pretty much covers it, esp. the answer from J.M.

Comment: Did yoy try trigonometric substitutions? like $1-x^2 = \cos^2(\theta)$?

Answer (score 2):

Set $x = \cos(\theta)$. This gives us $$I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{n/2}(\theta) \sin(k \cos(\theta)) \sin(\theta) d\theta = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(k \cos(\theta)) \sin^{n/2+1}(\theta) d\theta$$
The integral can be expressed in terms of the [Struve function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).

[$$H_{\alpha}(k) = \dfrac{2(k/2)^{\alpha}}{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(\alpha + 1/2)} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(k\cos(\theta)) \sin^{2 \alpha}(\theta) d \theta$$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function#Integral_form)
In our case, $\alpha = \dfrac{n}4 + \dfrac12$.

Hence, $$I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(k \cos(\theta)) \sin^{n/2+1}(\theta) d\theta = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(n/4+1)}{2(k/2)^{n/4+1/2}} H_{n/4+1/2}(k)$$